# To find total values of a sql coloumn as a month using php dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

Need to calculate the total SUM of any month dynamically using PHP and SQL query. Where in the values are real data, for every 3 min values keep coming to database.

```
$logs=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbcon,
                "SELECT (max(`WhReceived`) - min(`WhReceived`)) 
                as WhReceived ,(max(`WhDelivered`) - min(`WhDelivered`)) 
                as WhDelivered from parameterslog WHERE meterId='".$meter['id']."' 
                && `scanDateTime` >= '".date($_POST['month'])."' and `scanDateTime` <= '".date($_POST['month'])."'"));
```

tried this but not getting the sum.

Comment: Mysql or  SQL server ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from what i understand..

```
SELECT SUM(`total_value_to_calculate`) 
FROM `table_name` GROUP BY MONTH(`date`) ='12', YEAR(`date`)='2017'
```

Input: Month & Year
Output: Sum of Value

1. You will have to create a trigger to update the data with real time
2. You will get the updated value whenever you hit the PHP script.